# xml setAttribute throwing an error - NodeList object has no attribute setAttribute

Tags: python, xmldom

This one has me stumped, no attribute `setAttribute`. I'm assuming the meaning is that I cannot use `setAttribute` to modify the value. How else can I change what the current value is?

I have an xml file with patient data I need to modify/change. I've been able to change other text nodes without an issue. I can `getElementsByTagName()`, I then have to use `normalize()`, verify the object isn't null, then I can change the value by using `firstChild.nodeValue`, and then use `childNodes = [doc.createTextNode()`.

The value I'm trying to change though is a little different. I found out the hard way the elements I wanted to modify had a text node in between: `<element some data element>` The ones I need to modify appear to have attributes: `<telecom use = "HP" value = "1 (800) ...." />` but if I try the `setAttribute`, it throws the error. Within this telecom element, it can be a phone number or an email address. I already have the code to get the correct one I'm modifiying, just driving me nuts why I can change the value.
And, although I haven't gotten to that point yet, I can bet I'll have another problem writing this modified xml out to a file. (Just thinking out loud, nothing has really gone right so far, issue right now is with `setAttribute`)

this is a snippet of the xml file:

```
author>
    <time value="20190211160404-0700" />
    <assignedAuthor>
      <id root="2.16.840.9.9.9.99999" extension="99999999999" />
      <addr use="HP">
        <streetAddressLine>Urgent Care Clinic</streetAddressLine>
        <streetAddressLine>123 Anywhere Lane</streetAddressLine>
        <city>Denver</city>
        <state>CO</state>
        <postalCode>80000</postalCode>
      </addr>
      <telecom use="UP" value="tel:+1(800)999-4040" />
      <assignedPerson>
        <name>
          <given>Test</given>
          <family>Patient</family>
          <suffix>FG</suffix>
        </name>
      </assignedPerson>
      <representedOrganization>
        <id root="2.16.840.1.999999.0.999.99999" />
        <name>Urgent Care Clinic</name>
        <telecom value="mailto:johnwayne@dukes.edu" />
      </representedOrganization>
    </assignedAuthor>
  </
```

Code:

```
#This is how I have been modifying the attributes

for zipcode in doc.getElementsByTagName("postalCode"):
    if zipcode.firstChild is not None:
     zipcode.normalize()
     zipcode.firstChild.nodeValue = "80224"
     zipcode.childNodes = [doc.createTextNode("80224")]
    else:
     nodelist = doc.getElementsByTagName("postalCode").length 

#These approaches fail
for telecom in doc.getElementsByTagName("telecom"):
    phone = telecom.getAttribute("value")
    if telecom.firstChild is not None:
     telecom.normalize()
    if phone[0:4] in ["mail"]:  
    #phone.setAttribute("value", "anon@anon.com")
    #doc.getElementsByTagName("telecom").setAttribute("value", "anon@anon.com")
    phone.firstChild,nodeValue = "anon@anon.com"
    phone.childNodes = [doc.createTextNode("anon@anon.com")]
```

I would expect the telecom value to be modified. If it's not a text node or an attribute, what is it exactly and how can I change the value of it? 
When I use `phone.setAttribute("value", "anon@anon.com")` I would of expected the telecom value to change from: `<telecom value="mailto:johnwayne@dukes.edu" />` 
to `<telecom value="mailto:anon@anon.com" />`
Instead, I see the error:

> AttributeError: str object has no attribute setAttribute when I use `phone.setAttribute()`

and when I try
`doc.getElementsByTagName("telecom").setAttribute("value", "anon@anon.com")`,
I get the same error with a little twist,

> nodeList object has no attribute `setAttribute`

Comment: Can you include the actual error text you're getting, please?

Comment: Seems that `phone` is an attribute itself (`phone = telecom.getAttribute("value")`) and `getElementsByTagName` returns **list** of nodes so you have to use some loop and call `setAttribute` or  `doc.getElementsByTagName("telecom")[0].setAttribute("value", "anon@anon.com")`

Comment: You should be fine with `telecom.setAttribute("value", "mailto:anon@anon.com")`, `phone` is string, it has no `setAttribute`

Comment: Thank you for the responses. Barbsan, didn't see that last night, using telecom instead of phone. Occam's razor, just used telecom.setAttribute, does what it's supposed to do, thanks.